# c String ascending order function output is not available. Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c

**c String ascending order function output is not available.
Visual Studio 2022.

row 14
Error 1: An exception occurred (0x00007FF8449F63D4(ucrtbased.dll), hardwork.exe): 0xC0000005: An access violation occurred while writing location 0x00007FF6738F9CA4.
**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void SortString(char** aList, int index) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char ntemp[256];
    for (i = 0; i < index - 1; ++i) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < index; ++j) {
            if (strncmp(aList[i], aList[j], sizeof(ntemp)) > 0) {
                strcpy_s(ntemp, sizeof(ntemp), aList[i]);
                strcpy_s(aList[i], sizeof(ntemp), aList[j]);
                strcpy_s(aList[j], sizeof(ntemp), ntemp);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char* aList[5] = {
        "abc",
        "def",
        "ab",
        "bcd",
        "ae"
    };
    int i = 0;
    SortString(aList, 5);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", aList[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are trying to change the string literals that the pointers point at:

```c
strcpy_s(aList[i], sizeof(ntemp), aList[j]);
strcpy_s(aList[j], sizeof(ntemp), ntemp);
```

That's not allowed and also, the string literals lengths are not the same so if you tried copying `bcd` into `ae` it would write out of bounds.

Instead, swap the *pointers*:

```c
void SortString(char** aList, unsigned index) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i + 1 < index; ++i) {
        for (unsigned j = i + 1; j < index; ++j) {
            if (strcmp(aList[i], aList[j]) > 0) {
                // swap the pointers:
                char *ntemp = aList[i];
                aList[i] = aList[j];
                aList[j] = ntemp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since you are not allowed to overwrite string literals, you could instead change `aList` to be an array of `const char*`:

```c
const char* aList[5]
```

and adjust the `SortString` function accordingly. That would lead to a compilation error if you try to do `strcpy_s` into such a string literal - which is preferable over getting a runtime error.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MefK5T9E4)